# how can I match column fields and group their values together?

Tags: awk

I am sorting some files that I've created using pdfgrep, to list page numbers of certain PDFs that I have. it produced the following output:

```
./Buddhism in the Shadow of Brahmanism.pdf:111:      Then, rising from his seat, covering one shoulder with his robe, the king
./Buddhism in the Shadow of Brahmanism.pdf:182:branch who has adopted the yellow robes of Buddhism; he is sur-
./Buddhism in the Shadow of Brahmanism.pdf:229:       resolve that his body, his bowl, and his monastic robe (which had been
./Buddhism in the Shadow of Brahmanism.pdf:230:robe. In this way, Mahākāśyapa (or at least his body) is to act as a sort
./Buddhism in the Shadow of Brahmanism.pdf:230:corpse to his disciples and displays to them the Buddha’s robe, and they
./Buddhism in the Shadow of Brahmanism.pdf:230:offer him the robe that the Buddha had confided to him. Only then will
./Introduction to the History of Indian Buddhism.pdf:31:the robes of a Buddhist monk in an effort to convert them, he was Sciequia. For
./Introduction to the History of Indian Buddhism.pdf:54:monks, and in particular on retreat, robes, and chastity, p. 308.—On the life of
./Introduction to the History of Indian Buddhism.pdf:97:are the Kat.hināvadāna, which deals with the bowl, the staff, and the robes of
./Introduction to the History of Indian Buddhism.pdf:111:of a sort of robe.
./Introduction to the History of Indian Buddhism.pdf:112:cover his nakedness, and who rejects all other robes as superfluous.
./Introduction to the History of Indian Buddhism.pdf:127:noon, after having taken his robe and his bowl,
./Introduction to the History of Indian Buddhism.pdf:127:bowl and his robe, he went to the place where the Cāpāla caitya6 was located,
```

What I'm trying to do is group together the page numbers on the second column that match the file name, I was expecting the output to look something like:

```
./Buddhism in the Shadow of Brahmanism.pdf:111, 182, 229, 230
./Introduction to the History of Indian Buddhism.pdf:31, 54, 97, 111, 112, 127
```

I've tried using awk to parse the first value and then use those results on the same file to print only the page numbers so I could grep the result and append after the file name later, like so:

```
awk -F : '{print $1}' parsing_file | uniq | while read line; do awk -v number="$line" -F : '$1 == "$number" { print $2 }' parsing_file; done
```

But that didn't go through and I am guessing `uniq` and `while read` could be cut out, and maybe use some array with awk only?

I've seen something similar done here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167280/awk-group-by-and-sum-column-values

But instead of summing up the values on the columns, I just wanted to group them together.

Thanks

Comment: The first answer you got may be the best possible answer or it may not be. By accepting it right away you discourage other people from posting answers so you may never find out a better way to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Ed. Indeed, you're right, I didn't pay much attention for the full output of that answer, and I'm glad you answered it with one other possibility even if I had already marked it as solved. I still have to better grasp the mechanics of Forums usage. Thanks for your patience and time!

Comment: You're welcome. That part at least is easy - ask a question, give it a few hours or a day to see what answers you get (providing feedback/questions/comments to answers as appropriate you go) and **then** accept the one you're going to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk  -v OFS=":" '
match($0,/^\.\/.*\.pdf:[0-9]+/){
  value=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  split(value,arr,":")
  if(!seen[arr[1],arr[2]]++){
    name[arr[1]]=(name[arr[1]]?name[arr[1]]", ":"")arr[2]
  }
}
END{
  for(key in name){
    print key,name[key]
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows with your shown samples:

```
./Buddhism in the Shadow of Brahmanism.pdf:111, 182, 229, 230
./Introduction to the History of Indian Buddhism.pdf:31, 54, 97, 111, 112, 127
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk  -v OFS=":" '                   ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/^\.\/.*\.pdf:[0-9]+/){    ##Using match function to match from starting ./ till .pdf : digits as per shown samples.
  value=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)   ##Creating value with matched sub string here.
  split(value,arr,":")              ##Splitting value into array arr with : delimiter.
  if(!seen[arr[1],arr[2]]++){
     name[arr[1]]=(name[arr[1]]?name[arr[1]]", ":"")arr[2]  ##Creating name array with index of book name and its value it digits as per needed output.
  }
}
END{                                ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  for(key in name){                 ##Traversing through name here.
    print key,name[key]             ##Printing key and array value here.
  }
}
' Input_file                        ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

NOTE: previously above solution was not handling duplicate numbers coming for same paragraph so I had edited solution to take care of that case after Ed's answer.

Comment: I see you've fixed the issue of printing duplicate page numbers and not printing a `:` between  the title and the page numbers (but fix the output you show under "Output will be..." to include that `:`), good.

Comment: @EdMorton, Hi sir, I had added it, please do let me know if you see any issues, thank you.

Comment: I do see a few... I'll provide comments but then please wait til I'm done with all of them before updating  your code as the final comment will affect how you address earlier ones.

Comment: @EdMorton, yeah I have tried to fix them after reading your post. Sure, please do post here, I will try to fix if I could.

Comment: These are separate from anything listed in my post I think.

Comment: 1) You use `seen[arr[1],arr[2]]` but `arr[1],arr[2]` is just a slightly less robust version of `value` (`:` changed to SUBSEP) so just use `seen[value]`.

Comment: 2) You're isolating `value` using `match()` and then spliting `value` into `arr[]` on every `:` so you can use `arr[1]` and `arr[2]` to hold the title and page strings. It'd be much simpler to not do any of that and just set `FS` to `:` and then use `$1` and `$2` instead of `arr[1]` and `arr[2]`.

Comment: Actually I think those are really the only 2 points not alread mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @EdMorton, For 1st point(I saw experts(don't remember if its you or someone else here) not to change SUBSEP so I avoided, could update it in answer). 2nd point- I also thought to set field separators first but then I thought to use regex rather than field separator(in case OP's real data is having some other stuff too but that's an assumption only), thank you sir.

Comment: I wasn't in any way suggesting you change SUBSEP in this case (but there's nothing wrong with setting it to the same value as OFS for example when convenient for storing and printing compound indices - `arr[$1,$2,$3]=7;... for (i in arr) print i, arr[i]`). What I was saying in that point is that you already have the string stored in `value` that contains the same string as `arr[1] ":" arr[2]` and so you could be using `value` as the index rather than creating a new almost identical compound index from `arr[1] SUBSEP arr[2]`.

Comment: If the OPs real data has `:`s in the title then your `split(value,arr,":")` will fail in exactly the same way as setting FS to `:` would on a `:` in the title (or, far less likely, page number). If the OPs real data has titles that don't match your regexp otherwise (e.g. they aren't PDFs) then its most likely they'll want them handled exactly the same way as in the sample input. If they have lines of input that look nothing like that then they'd have to provide that info in the question for us to know how to handle them.

Comment: @EdMorton, Sure sir points taken, thank you for your nice suggestions as always, I will try to learn from them, cheers, be safe, stay healthy sir.

Comment: You're welcome. The main issue though is something you can't solve without turning your answer into mine and that is that storing all of the data in memory and then printing it in a loop in the END section is always a worse approach to these types of problem in terms of memory usage and efficiency than sorting the input on the key values just printing the data every time a key value changes.

Comment: @EdMorton, yeah but if data is not sorted then it could be helpful(in case someone not using sort/uniq etc), cheers and have a Good day. NOTE: I have also added a note, that changes were made after seeing your post for duplicate digits removing, I missed it :(

Comment: Fair enough - if you can sort your input in advance for printing one key at a time then you should do that but if you can't sort it for some reason then you have to store at least all of the output in memory for outputing in the END.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=":" }
$1 != title {
    if ( title != "" ) {
        print title, pages
    }
    title = $1
    pages = $2
    delete seen
    next
}
!seen[$2]++ {
    pages = pages ", " $2
}
END {
    print title, pages
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
./Buddhism in the Shadow of Brahmanism.pdf:111, 182, 229, 230
./Introduction to the History of Indian Buddhism.pdf:31, 54, 97, 111, 112, 127
```

The differences between the above and [@Ravinder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66841825/1745001) as I write this (which is after that answer was accepted) are:

1. This relies on your input being sorted by title and page number as shown in the example in your question while Ravinders doesn't. If your real data isn't sorted then run `sort -t':' -k1,1 -k2,2n file | awk ...'`.
2. This doesn't read all of the titles and page numbers into memory, it just reads the page numbers for 1 title at a time, so it'll work no matter how massive your input file is.
3. This will output the titles in the same order they appear in the input instead of a random order.
4. This produces the expected output by only outputting unique page numbers per title rather than the same
   page number being output every time it appears in the input (e.g.
   `111, 182, 229, 230` vs `111, 182, 229, 230, 230, 230`.
5. This produces the expected output by puting a `:` between the title and the first page number instead of a blank.